# How can I use Urdu in Webpages?

Tags: web, html, urdu

I want to use Urdu in my webpage to develop a website in Urdu Language... Please help me out, how can I find my required Webpage using Urdu Language?

Comment: static or fetch from db or else

Comment: issue has resolved or not? (Hogya kya?)

Comment: Static.... i haven't tried it yet.... may be i can find more helpful if yu tell me briefly about that..?

Comment: if u think my answer give u some help than mark as accepted this will to others who face this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use URDU language inside the HTML, than you need to save your `.HTML` file with

```
Encode in UTF-8
```